# Prove that $\sum\limits_{\mathrm{cyc}} xy^2+xyz \Big [1+\frac23 \sum\limits_{\mathrm{cyc}} (x^2 - xy) \Big] \leq 4$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, contest-math

> Let $x,y,z \geqslant 0$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2+xyz=4$. Prove that
> $$xy^2+yz^2+zx^2+xyz \Big [1+\frac23 (x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx) \Big] \leq 4  .$$

Die a lot of brain cell with this one ( 4 years already). I don't think the usual trig or algebraic substitutes work for this inequality !!!

Comment: Have you tried Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: with computer for finding all roots (using Julia language), yes. This inequality is true BTW. I am looking for elementary sol.

Comment: The Buffalo Way (BW) works. But it is quite complicated.

Comment: Maybe helpful (1): The substitution $x=\frac{2\sqrt{ab}}{\sqrt{\left(c+a\right)\left(c+b\right)}};y=\frac{2\sqrt{bc}}{\sqrt{\left(a+b\right)\left(a+c\right)}};z=\frac{2\sqrt{ca}}{\sqrt{\left(b+c\right)\left(b+a\right)}}$ matches the condition $x^2+y^2+z^2+xyz=4$. You can then use any $a,b,c \ge0$ and continue.

Comment: Maybe helpful (2): Let the mean $m = (x+y+z)/3$. Then the term $\frac23 (x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx) = \sum_{cyc} (x-m)^2$ and the condition $4= x^2+y^2+z^2+xyz=\sum_{cyc} (x-m)^2 + 3m^2 + xyz$.

Comment: Maybe helpful (3): Some auxiliary inequalities can be proven: $xyz \le 1$, $xy+yz+zx \le x+y+z \le 3$, $xy+yz+zx \le 2 + xyz$, $ 2 \le x+y+z $.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f=xy^2+\cdots+xyz(\cdots),g=x^2+y^2+z^2+xyz-4$

If we use an optimization software, then we get $\max(f)$ when $g=0,x,y,z\geq 0$, that is $4$ only for $x=y=z=1$.

Possibly the software (because of the gradient methods) may forget values of $(x,y,z)$ improving the maximum. If we want to be sure of the result, we can use the Lagrange method; but often the calculations are very complicated (here we consider 4 algebraic equations with 4 unknowns). I used the computer to solve the system.

$\bullet$Case 1.$(x,y,z)$ is not in the edge of $(\mathbb{R}^+)^3$, that is $x,y,z>0$

Then the $(4\times 4)$ system is $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}+a\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x}=0,\cdots,g=0$ with unknows $x,y,z,a$.

This system has $46$ solutions in $\mathbb{C}^3$, but only one of them is $>0: (1,1,1)$

$\bullet$Case 2.For example $x=0$, Then we search $\max(yz^2)$ when $y^2+z^2=4,y,z\geq 0$.

We substitute $y=2\cos(u),z=2\sin(u)$ where $u\in [0,\pi/2]$ and it is easy to see that the maximum of $8\cos(u)\sin(u)^2$ is $\dfrac{16}{3\sqrt{3}}<4$.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment :

I use the substitution @Andreas .

I try to eliminate a part of the inequality and it seems we have the inequalities for $u,v,w\in(0,1]$ such that  :

$$a=2\sqrt{\frac{uv}{\left(w+u\right)\left(w+v\right)}},b=2\sqrt{\frac{uw}{\left(v+u\right)\left(w+v\right)}},c=2\sqrt{\frac{wv}{\left(w+u\right)\left(u+v\right)}}$$ then it seems we have

$$g(a,b,c)\leq f(a,b,c)\leq 4$$

Where :

$$g(a,b,c)=ab^{2}+bc^{2}+ca^{2}+abc\left(1+\frac{2}{3}(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}-ab-bc-ca)\right)$$

And :

$$f(a,b,c)=\left(1-abc\right)\left(ab^{2}+bc^{2}+ca^{2}\right)+\left(2abc-1\right)+abc+2$$

I don't know if it's simpler but let's try it .

Hope it helps in some way .

Comment: @RiverLi Can you show it in a simple mannner ?

Comment: $f(a, b, c ) \le 4$ is not true.

Comment: @RiverLi have you a counter-example (to correct the inequality) ?Thanks you .

Comment: Yes, I have found counter-example some days ago. But I did not record it. You can find it yourself. Method: Generate random $u, v, w$, then you get $a, b, c$, then check if $f(a,b,c) \le 4$.

Answer (score 0):

If $xyz=0$, it is easy to prove the desired inequality.

In the following, assume that $x, y, z > 0$.

We use the known substitutions: $a, b, c > 0$,
\begin{align*}
 x &= \frac{2a}{\sqrt{(c+a)(a+b)}},\\
 y &= \frac{2b}{\sqrt{(a+b)(b+c)}},\\
 z &= \frac{2c}{\sqrt{(b+c)(c+a)}}.
\end{align*}
(See e.g. [If $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 2xyz = 1$ then $x+ y+ z \leq \frac{3}{2}?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2193559/if-x2-y2-z2-2xyz-1-then-x-y-z-leq-frac32))

We have
\begin{align*}
 xy^2 + yz^2 + zx^2
 &= \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{8bc^2}{(a+b)(b+c)^2(c+a)}\sqrt{(a+b)(b+c)}\\
 &= \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{8bc^2}{(a+b)(b+c)^2(c+a)}\left(b + \frac{a+c}{2}\right)\sqrt{1 - \frac{(a-c)^2}{(2b + a + c )^2}}\\
 &\le \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{8bc^2}{(a+b)(b+c)^2(c+a)}\left(b + \frac{a+c}{2}\right)
 \left(1 - \frac{(a-c)^2}{2(2b + a + c )^2}\right)
\end{align*}
where we have used
$\sqrt{1 - q} \le 1 - q/2$ for all $q\le 1$.

We have
$$xyz = \frac{8abc}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}$$
and
$$x^2+y^2+z^2 = \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{4b^2}{(a+b)(b+c)}.$$

We have
\begin{align*}
 xy + yz + zx &= \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{4ca }{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}\sqrt{(a+b)(b+c)}\\
 &= \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{4ca }{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}\left(b + \frac{a+c}{2}\right)\sqrt{1 - \frac{(a-c)^2}{(2b + a + c )^2}}\\
 &\ge \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{4ca }{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}\left(b + \frac{a+c}{2}\right)\left(1 - \frac{(a-c)^2}{(2b + a + c )^2}\right)\\
 &= \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{8ca}{(c+a)(2b + a + c)}
\end{align*}
where we have used
$\sqrt{1 - q} \ge 1 - q$
for all $q \in [0,1]$.

Thus, it suffices to prove that, for all $a, b, c > 0$,
\begin{align*}
 &\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{8bc^2}{(a+b)(b+c)^2(c+a)}\left(b + \frac{a+c}{2}\right)
 \left(1 - \frac{(a-c)^2}{2(2b + a + c )^2}\right) \\
 & + \frac{8abc}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)} \left[1 + \frac23\left(\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{4b^2}{(a+b)(b+c)} - \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{8ca}{(c+a)(2b + a + c)}\right)\right]\\
 & \le 4
\end{align*}
or (after clearing the denominators)
\begin{align*}
 &12\,{a}^{7}{b}^{2}+18\,{a}^{7}bc+6\,{a}^{7}{c}^{2}+42\,{a}^{6}{b}^{3}+
 29\,{a}^{6}{b}^{2}c-10\,{a}^{6}b{c}^{2}+9\,{a}^{6}{c}^{3} +42\,{a}^{5}{
  b}^{4}\\
 &\quad -49\,{a}^{5}{b}^{3}c-68\,{a}^{5}{b}^{2}{c}^{2}-148\,{a}^{5}b{c}^
 {3}+15\,{a}^{5}{c}^{4}+15\,{a}^{4}{b}^{5} -122\,{a}^{4}{b}^{4}c+42\,{a}
 ^{4}{b}^{3}{c}^{2} \\
 &\quad +3\,{a}^{4}{b}^{2}{c}^{3} -122\,{a}^{4}b{c}^{4}+42\,{
  a}^{4}{c}^{5}+9\,{a}^{3}{b}^{6} -148\,{a}^{3}{b}^{5}c+3\,{a}^{3}{b}^{4}
 {c}^{2}+537\,{a}^{3}{b}^{3}{c}^{3}\\
 &\quad+42\,{a}^{3}{b}^{2}{c}^{4}-49\,{a}^{
  3}b{c}^{5}+42\,{a}^{3}{c}^{6} +6\,{a}^{2}{b}^{7}-10\,{a}^{2}{b}^{6}c-68
 \,{a}^{2}{b}^{5}{c}^{2}+42\,{a}^{2}{b}^{4}{c}^{3}\\
 &\quad +3\,{a}^{2}{b}^{3}{c}
 ^{4}-68\,{a}^{2}{b}^{2}{c}^{5} +29\,{a}^{2}b{c}^{6}+12\,{a}^{2}{c}^{7}+
 18\,a{b}^{7}c+29\,a{b}^{6}{c}^{2}-49\,a{b}^{5}{c}^{3}\\
&\quad-122\,a{b}^{4}{c}
 ^{4} -148\,a{b}^{3}{c}^{5}-10\,a{b}^{2}{c}^{6}+18\,ab{c}^{7}+12\,{b}^{7
 }{c}^{2}+42\,{b}^{6}{c}^{3}+42\,{b}^{5}{c}^{4}\\
&\quad +15\,{b}^{4}{c}^{5}+9\,{
  b}^{3}{c}^{6}+6\,{b}^{2}{c}^{7}\\
 &\ge 0.
\end{align*}
This inequality can be proved using [BW (Buffalo Way)](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h522084).

We are done.